# Cronjob for deleting temporary accounts?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small pay for use web app.

I would like to allow people to trial the app before they pay.

To do this, I would like to have a system where temporary user accounts are created, then deleted again after 30 minutes or so.

The first thing that comes to mind is adding a column "isTemp" of type TINYINT to the accounts table, then setting a cronjob to execute the query "DELETE FROM accounts WHERE isTemp = 1" every 30 minutes.

However...  I am a bit nervous about this.  I have fears of waking up in the morning to find the entire accounts table empty.  I realize this may be an irrational fear, but I don't like scheduled DELETE statements coming near the accounts table.  :)

What are thoughts on this?  Is this the way it should be done?  Or should I rethink this?

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Comment: I would add a `liveUntil` date-time field as well, and when allowing people to log in/checking whether they are still active, you can add a `liveUntil > NOW()` clause. That way, accounts will be effectively disabled after this time, but you do not need to run any `DELETE` queries to achieve this. On the flip side of this though - if you don't want to schedule a `DELETE` query, how are you going to get rid of the temp accounts? I'm pretty sure you don't want to be doing it manually for the rest of your life, and you'd just be running that same query anyway...

Comment: Or you could create a `temp_accounts` table, and `UNION ALL` it with the `accounts` table when selecting from it, so that your `DELETE` query is run against only the `temp_accounts` table, but you can still find temp and permanent users in a single query.

Comment: @DaveRandom - Thanks, I do intend to schedule the task in some form.  I am just wondering if having a DELETE WHERE isTemp = 1 is safe, (is there any extremely unlikely scenario where accounts with an isTemp value of 0 could be deleted?)

Comment: @DaveRandon - just saw your second comment.  Thanks, I would feel much safer with something like that.

Comment: The only way a query would delete records that you did not ask it to is if the database became corrupted. In which case, you would probably have bigger problems than a couple of missing accounts - I think a more important thing to deal with here is to make sure you have a regular backup of all important information in your database.

Answer (score 1):

The optimal solution would be to `active` and `inactive` accounts. However, if this is not easily done with your current coding, then a `DELETE` may suffice. I would recommend creating a `datetime` field of when the user account is created. You can just create a simple cron job to go ahead and check for `signup time + 30 mins` or something to that effect, and then `DELETE`. If this worries you, have the script email you manually for the first few days and do the action manually to ensure it's working properly.

The good thing about using `active` and `inactive` is that it's just a simple bool change rather than losing all of the data.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah I agree with this (tho column should be accountStatus [trial,paid,inactive]), its better to keep all record incase the user wants to continue the service, then its as simple as changing from trial to paid or after trial to inactive. User might not want to enter all his info again.. Plus within an admin control section admin can see all clients past & present with juicy "correspondence" emails. if deleted then there gone for good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if a user logs in at minute 29, your system will delete them at minute 30, their account will be deleted even though it has only been active for 1min.

You would be better doing a "DELETE FROM accounts WHERE isTemp = 1 AND account_created > {30 mins ago}

(Insert code to work out a timestamp greater than 30mins ago)

p.s. 30mins is not a long time for a temporary account - perhaps 2 hours -